# Is "oceans past" correct against "past oceans"?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

I came across this phrase on NY Times mais page:

"echoes of oceans past"

shouldn't it be written:

"echoes of past oceans" instead??

Or is there any difference?

Answer (score 2):

Inverting the adjective order is **poetic** usage here, and it fits the idea of some 'echo' from a 'past ocean'.

I've never known any kind of horizontal surface to actually produce an echo, which usually comes from a vertical surface. The 'echo' might be intended as an artifact of the mind: a memory. Or just an allusion to something, since 'past oceans' exist on a geological time scale.

Or perhaps the writer is sitting beside the ocean and hearing the sound of surf – white noise, wherein the mind can easily imagine any other noise which it evokes, similar to cloud-gazing.

Comment: It's definitely a poetic usage, evoking expressions such as "Remembrance of Things Past" (the old-fashioned English title of Proust's novel) as well as more recent things like the X-Men story "Days of Future Past".